# Textbox lostfocus event doesn't fire when using a default button

Tags: textbox, vb6, lostfocus, defaultbutton

Today I stumbled upon a problem with a `LostFocus` event from a `TextBox` that didn't fire. Most clients didn't have any problems but a small portion of them reported unexpected behavior. After some research I found that the clients who didn't had the problem clicked on the "Ok" button with the mouse while the other clients pressed `Enter` on their keyboard. The "Ok" button was the default button on the Form so pressing `Enter` should work just fine. The problem is that pressing `Enter` doesn't fire a `LostFocus` event on the TextBox with focus.

After some Googling it was pretty clear that this is the expected behavior of a default button. The focus never loses the `TextBox` and the code behind the `CommandButton` `Click` event is being run without it being clicked.

How to get the `LostFocus` event to fire when using a default button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple hack that worked for me is to set the focus to the "Ok" button whenever the `Click` event is being fired. That way the current control automatically runs its `LostFocus` event. Don't forget to put an extra `DoEvents` after setting the focus. Otherwise the `LostFocus` event fire after your other code has been executed.

```
Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
    cmdOK.SetFocus
    DoEvents
    'Run your other code
End Sub
```